# Validate POST request (Vue + DRF)

Tags: python, django, vue.js, django-rest-framework

So here's expected flow of the request:

1. The  user creates a new `Language` via an html form. [√ ]
2. Vue via axios will fire a POST request to drf. [√ ]
3. Drf will validate the data from the POST request (see if the language name/id/etc already exists) [x]
4. Create the new language if it passes the validation. [x]

I'm currently stuck on #3.

I tried putting this on my `LanguageViewSet`:

```
def post(self, request):
    language = request.data.get('language')
    serializer = LanguageSerializer(data=language)
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        language_saved = serializer.save()
    return Response({"success": "Language '{}' created successfully!".format(language_saved.name)})
```

However, this doesn't somewhat work and gets completely ignored since:

1. I tried commenting the post function, but still if I call a POST request via axios on the `LanguageViewSet` it would still post. probably a built-in POST feature?
2. If the function is there, notice I used  `language = request.data.get('language')` which means on my axios, the name of my data to be sent should be `language` right? otherwise it would ignore the POST request. I used `created_lang` in axios, fired the POST req but still it posted without any errors as if it completely ignored my post function.
3. If I tried posting a new language of which it's name is already registered on the database, it would still create it making duplicate records.

Forgive my naiveness I am completely new to drf and django :<

Here's my codes:

`Language` model:

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='New Language')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Its `serializer`:

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Language
        fields = ['id', 'name']
```

`view`:

```
class LanguageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Language.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = LanguageSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Language.objects.all().order_by('name')
        lang = self.request.query_params.get('lang','')
        if lang:
            return Language.objects.filter(pk=lang)
        else:
            return queryset
```

and `url`:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'languages', views.LanguageViewSet)
```

On my frontend, here's my form:

```
<form @submit.prevent="PostLanguage" class="mt-3" action='' method="POST">
    <input type="text" v-model="created_lang.name" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Language Name" autocomplete="off" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Post">
</form>
```

And will be posted by this simple Vue script:

```
PostLanguage(){
    let params = Object.assign({}, this.created_lang)
    axios.post(
        'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/languages/', params
    )
    .then(response=>{
        console.log(response)
        this.GetLanguages()
        this.created_lang.name = ''
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

## Update

I tried this:

```
class LanguageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Language
    fields = ['id', 'name']

def validate_name(self, value):
    existed_language = Language.objects.filter(name=value).get()
    if existed_language.name == value:
        return Response(status=400)
    else:
        return value
```

if the `name` data from the POST is new (it's not used in the database) it would then return the `value` of it thus creating a new language. However if it already exists, I tried returning a response but it would create a language with its name  = `<Response status_code=400, "text/html; charset=utf-8">`. I know it's kinda funny but I think this is a step to the right direction.

Comment: is language is unique ?

Comment: @a_k_v yes it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If language is unique in your model then add unique true in your model definition.

```
class Language(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='New Language', unique=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This will cause serializer.validate to fail and won't create duplicate languages.

Update

The validate_name in your serializer returns the value of the filed after executing the validation logic. So you can update it with `raise serializers.ValidationError("Language already exist")` instead of Response (400) statement.

Comment: Thanks so much!! I have a couple more inquiries before wrapping this up. 1. Which is better? setting the model's `unique=True` or writing its own validator in its serializer? 2. Within the returned response namely `error.response.request` there's a field: `response: "{"name":["Language already exist"]}"` how can I get this returned text? Thanks so much again! :)

Comment: For your first query its good to set unique true in model level. because every time you may not use serializer to insert data to the model. In that case the validation in your serializer useless.

Comment: and about the error message that is the general format for the error message in django.